Biblatex chicago how to revise
I am trying to update the biblatex to match the below style. I have tried many ways but I don't get to match the style. I have gone over stack exchange queries multiple times but I am still lost. Any help from the latex community will be greatly appreciated.
I use the following code:
Here is the full code
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{setspace,graphics,epstopdf,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,versionPO}
\usepackage{marginnote,datetime,subfigure,enumitem,rotating,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{hyperref,float}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,longtable}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, dashed=false,  maxbibnames=999,  maxcitenames=3, strict, natbib]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\AtEveryCite{%
 % \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\begin{document}


\citet{dang2020information}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

I get the following from this code :

[1] TriViDang, GaryGorton, and Bengt Holmstrom. “The information view of financial crises.” Annual Review of Financial Economics 12.1 (2020), pp. 39–65

I need to convert this to the following but I don't manage:

TriViDang, GaryGorton, and Bengt Holmstrom. “The information view of financial crises,” Annual Review of Financial Economics 12.1 (2020), 39–65.

I will really appreciate any help and leads -- thanks so much!

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the short compilable TeX code you have used so far. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Thanks very much Mensch! Please see below the full TEX code I use on the Overleaf.
There is a small amendment that is needed but I really don't manage ... any support will be appreciated ...

In my answer below I only address the most obvious issue with your code. If you still need to change something about the output, I suggest you ask a new question (ideally already taking into account the answers you get here). Make sure to ask only about one concrete problem/issue/change per question and not about several things at once.

Apart from an error about versionPO.sty not being found your example code also produces the following message for me

! Package xkeyval Error: `authordate' undefined in families `blx@opt@pre'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                 
l.16297 \blx@processoptions


Indeed, there is no biblatex style called authordate. Since you mention Chicago style, I presume you want biblatex-chicago's authordate style, in which case you should load biblatex not directly, but via the biblatex-chicago wrapper package.
Simplified MWE
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate,
  backend=biber,
  uniquename=false, uniquelist=false,
  dashed=false, maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=3,
  strict,
  natbib,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\AtEveryCite{%
 % \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\begin{document}


\citet{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography

\end{document}


This gives correct Chicago author-date style (minus the forced square brackets).
